# MongoDB find but null, empty or non-existing

Tags: mongodb, null, find

I'm trying to run a script to convert a Status.date field to ISODate format. When I run the operation below:

```
var cursor = db.teste.find({"Status.date": {$exists: true, $ne: [null,""]}}); 
while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
   var doc = cursor.next(); 
   db.teste.update(
    {"_id": doc._id}, 
    {"$set": {"Status.date": new Date(doc.Status.date)}}
   ) 
}
```

It converts the fields that have dates allright, but the one with *null* or "" return the following:

```
  "date": ISODate("1969-12-31T21:00:00.000-03:00")
```

I think I'm having a syntax problem inside $ne, but not sure what it is. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

1. Case null

Expected input:

```
{ 
    _id: ObjectId("610418846df5452eacdd81c1"),
    "Status": {
        "dateTime": null
    }
}
```

Expected output (keep null unchanged!):

```
{ 
    _id: ObjectId("610418846df5452eacdd81c1"),
    "Status": {
        "dateTime": null
    }
}
```

2. Case empty

Expected input:

```
{ 
    _id: ObjectId("610418846df5452eacdd81c1"),
    "Status": {
        "dateTime": ''
    }
}
```

Expected output (keep '' unchanged!):

```
{ 
    _id: ObjectId("610418846df5452eacdd81c1"),
    "Status": {
        "dateTime": ''
    }
}
```

3. Case dd/mm/YYYY

Expected input:

```
{ 
    _id: ObjectId("610418846df5452eacdd81c1"),
    "Status": {
        "dateTime": 30/06/2020
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{ 
    _id: ObjectId("610418846df5452eacdd81c1"),
    "Status": {
        "dateTime": ISODate("2020-06-30T00:00:00.000-03:00")
    }
}
```

4. Case YYYY-mm-dd

Expected input:

```
{ 
    _id: ObjectId("610418846df5452eacdd81c1"),
    "Status": {
        "dateTime": 2020-06-30
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{ 
    _id: ObjectId("610418846df5452eacdd81c1"),
    "Status": {
        "dateTime": ISODate("2020-06-30T00:00:00.000-03:00")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example input and desired output? Also, I think is a better way using `db.teste.update(...)` to avoid `while` loop.

Comment: Try the condition as: exists is true _or_ not equals null _or_ not equals empty string. A better way would be to use **Update With Aggregation Pipeline**, and avoid the cursor and the while-loop.

Comment: Correction (the condition): (exists is true) _and_ (not equals null or not equals empty string).

Comment: Is `doc.Status.date` expected to contain integers?

Comment: I've added in/out examples for each possibility I have, for clarification. The field is expected to contain *null*, empty spaces '' and strings in dd/mm/YYYY and YYYY-mm-dd formats